# cannot use MemoryAnalyzer-1.7

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I just downloaded `MemoryAnalyzer-1.7.0.20170613-macosx.cocoa.x86_64.zip` from [official website](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php) , unzip it got mat.app move it to Applications, then open it, but in the interface I cannot click anything , that is the click does not have any effect. Even I cannot close it, I have to force quit it.

[image]

---

supplementary

I could use MemoryAnalyzer plug-in in eclipse IDE successfully

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you install the [MemoryAnalyzer as plug-in](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/memory-analyzer-0) into an [Eclipse package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/)?

Comment: @howlger Sorry I do not have eclipse in my mac, I use idea instead. Could it have some error log?

Comment: Try to install the [_Eclipse IDE for Java Developers_](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/oxygen2) plus the [MemoryAnalyzer plug-in](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/memory-analyzer-0). The Eclipse log file is in the workspace: `.metadata/.log`.

Comment: @howlger I have tried, I could use it this way successfully. Please see my supplementary info in the main post.

Comment: @howlger I forgot submit the edit

Comment: Maybe it is caused by the following (MemoryAnalyzer 1.7 has been released June 2017, before macOS 10.13): https://www.eclipse.org/org/press-release/20170925criticalbug.php

Comment: @howlger but my machine is version:10.11.6 (15G18013)

Comment: I see. Do you have Java 9? Is the question already answered for you, or would you like to find out the exact reason?

Comment: @howlger Yeah, I had java9, but the JAVA_HOME is `jdk1.8.0_91.jdk`. I just want to feedback this problem that in my machine(OS X 10.1.6) I cannot use standalone MemoryAnalyzer 1.7 and the symptom is that you cannot click anything in the interface, so if somebody met this same problem he do not need take time to try every manner to resolve it , and just use MemoryAnalyzer plug-in instead.